# Using R and Leaflet, how can I get my map to display numbers formatted with commas?

Tags: r, leaflet

Here is data to reproduce a sample of counties used in my map:

```
packages <- c('dplyr','leaflet','sf','USAboundaries')
lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE)

ca_counties <- USAboundaries::us_counties(states = 'CA')

parcels <- structure(list(county = c("Yuba", "Sacramento", "Inyo"), num.parcels = c(27797L, 
452890L, 6432L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

parcels <- st_as_sf(left_join(parcels, ca_counties[,c('name')], by = c("county" = "name")))
```

Here is the code to produce my map:

```
bins <- c(1, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000, 600000)
pal <- colorBin("Blues", domain = parcels$num.parcels, bins = bins)

labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s County</strong><br/>
  Parcels: %g<br/>",
  parcels$county, parcels$num.parcels
  ) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)

leaflet(parcels) %>%
  setView(-119, 37.9, 6) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(
    fillColor = ~pal(num.parcels),
    weight = 2,
    opacity = 1,
    color = 'black',
    dashArray = '2',
    fillOpacity = 0.7,
    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "red", weight = 3,
                                        bringToFront = TRUE),
    label = labels,
    labelOptions = labelOptions(
      style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "4px 8px"),
      textsize = "15px",
      direction = 'auto')) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~num.parcels, opacity = 0.7, title = "Number of Parcels",
            position = "bottomleft")
```

This produces a leaflet map where hovering over a county displays the number of parcels for that county. I would like these numbers to be formatted with commas, e.g. '6,432' instead of '6432.'

I've tried a few solutions. First, I tried changing the sprintf statement that defines labels to see if there's a way to get numbers formatted with commas. Second, it tried running:

```
parcels$num.parcels <- format(parcels$num.parcels, big.mark = ',')
```

This gives me problems later on when running the leaflet code because the variable is no longer numeric. Third, I tried to see if there was a way to do this directly in the labelOptions statement but was not able to find any way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `scales` package this can be achieved like so

```
labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s County</strong><br/>
  Parcels: %s<br/>",
  parcels$county, scales::number_format(big.mark = ",")(parcels$num.parcels)
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
```